# What is difference between "with only" and "only with"?

Tags: difference, transatlantic-differences

For the following two sentences:

> "He can find out the solution of the problem **only with** the information about the fundamental theorem of calculus," and
>
> "He can find out the solution of the problem **with only** the information about the fundamental theorem of calculus,"

what is different from the language interpretation point of view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case 1: the information about the theorem is necessary for him to find the solution but he might need other information too.

Case 2: the information about the theorem is all he needs to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

it's all in the nuance of the implied negative:

Case 1: The information is absolutely necessary. Other sources of information may clarify, but he must definitely have the mentioned information in order to find the solution, he cannot find the solution without it.

Case 2: If he uses this information, he can find the solution without recourse to any other information. It says nothing about whether or not he can find solution using other information, only that if he uses the mentioned information, he does not need other information.